# some inquiries in working with jFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have a j tree in the left side of the window, I want to make every node in it have a different content when clicking on it. but with in the same window.

(example: same as what we have in our computers, downloads, documents, pictures, ...etc )

I want to know how its done.

And I would like to display a document with a long text and some pictures in some of the nodes, I want to know the best way of doing that.

Comment: Is the number of tree nodes always the same?  Do you know the content for each node in advance, or do you need to build it the moment a tree node is selected?

Comment: i know the content, when a node is selected i want the content to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Place a JPanel that uses a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) in the center of your window.  Then add each node's content to that panel.  CardLayout shows only one of its children at a time, and will always have a preferred size that accommodates all of the children, both visible and invisible.

Display long text using a [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) (if it's all in the same font), a [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) (if it's predefined HTML that you are packaging with your application), or a [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) (if the text is dynamic, and has images and/or uses multiple fonts).  All of those should have [setEditable(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable-boolean-) called on them, and should be placed in a JScrollPane.